# First layer - not even infill

Tags: slic3r, repetier, infill

I'm using Repetier and Slic3r and it is printing a gap between the perimeter and infill on the first layer. 
Also, the infill is lifting (as in photo).
Any advise?

[image: infill issue]

Comment: I've never seen that kind of lifting, but are you sure that's perimeter on the outside and not a skirt? My best guess is that either the filament diameter or nozzle diameter is wrong in Slic3r.

Comment: The gap could be a wrong configuration in Slic3r for your printer. For the lifting try: thicker layers, higher bed temperature, bed leveling, different filament.

Comment: Are you trying to print directly on the PCB? Not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I was printing on glass with hairspray as adhesive (can't see it in photo). My solution posted below as answer.

Comment: It looks like the right side is much smoother then the left side, so I'm going t guess your bed isn't leveled.

Answer (score 3):

You're not sticking to your bed. Adjust your bed height. You are too far.
Otherwise you are going too fast and or too hot.

Calibrate the bed. Reduce speed. Then adjust temps.

Also could be material contamination

See this link for a visual troubleshooting.

http://reprap.org/wiki/Print_Troubleshooting_Pictorial_Guide

http://support.3dverkstan.se/article/23-a-visual-ultimaker-troubleshooting-guide

In addition use some gluestick. That will often solve these issues. Last but not least add a raft if it continues. Or just ignore it. My bet is temp is too hot. I also like to smash my first layer, but not everyone likes that technique as it causes elephant footing.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works for me.

I have increased my first layer extrusion width to 250 %, reduced the print speed of perimeters to 30 mm/s, reduced the brim width to 1 and increased the infill/perimeter overlap to 30 %.

This was PLA with heat bed off (no heating), printing on glass and using hairspray as an adhesive.  Most of my settings were on default. (Repetier & Slic3r).

Comment: This is not a solution, this is a kludge. The *real* problem is probably that the nozzle is too far from the build plate (or grave underextrusion, but you'd notice that from the rest of the print).

Comment: So, it appears the "perimeter" is actually a brim. I've never needed a brim so far, and based on your image, I would say that you don't need one, either. I think Tom is right about the rest.

Answer (score 1):

I was having these issues too on a CR-10S and I worked on it for months and the only thing that would fix it was the spread, overlap, and width of the extrusion, this may also be caused by the fact that I haven't really tried to use glue stick or anything to get my prints to stick better.